# isinstance returning false when class is the same?

Tags: python

```
def addError(self, e):
    if not isinstance(e, Error):
        raise ValueError('{0} is not type {0}'.format(e, Error))
    self.__errors.append(e)
```

Message:

ValueError: `<class 'api.utils.Error'>` is not type `<class 'api.utils.Error'>`

Comment: waaaaait... what the heck?

Comment: Hang on.. If it's printed, doesn't that mean `isinstance(e, Error)` returns `True`?

Comment: sorry i was debugging...and i pasted the code after

Comment: @aiKid ill mark your answer correct because once i read it i double checked my work and i was passing Error instead of the variable error. thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're passing the class *itself*, not an instance of the class. That explains your problem.

```
>>> class A:
    pass

>>> isinstance(A, A)
False
```

What you probably want is to check an instance:

```
>>> isinstance(A(), A)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

`e` is the class `api.utils.Error`, not an instance of the class. You may want to construct an instance.

Additionally, your format string has a bug:

```
'{0} is not type {0}'
```

This ignores the second argument to `format` and uses the first one for both placeholders. You most likely meant the following:

```
'{0} is not type {1}'
```

or on Python 2.7,

```
'{} is not type {}'
```